# $(this) not working in Ionic3

Tags: jquery, ionic-framework

I am using Jquery cdn for my Ionic 3 project.
Whenever, I clicked on the checkbox, entire row of the checkbox need to be highlighted. I am using $(this) keyword but it is not working as expected.

**part.html**

```
<tbody id="bodytest">
      <tr *ngFor="let item of parts; let i=index" class="pt-4" id="row">
        <td><ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.selected" (ionChange)="updateCartArray(item)"></ion-checkbox></td>
        <td style="text-align:center">{{i+1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.partNumber}}</td>
        <td>{{item.description}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**part.ts**

```
updateCartArray(item){
    if(item.selected){
      this.cartItems.push(item);
    } else{
      this.cartItems.splice(this.cartItems.indexOf(item),1);
    }
    console.log(this.cartItems);
    $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('checkJquery');
  }
```

**part.scss**

```
.checkJquery{
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: try jQuery(this) instead

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be a reference to?

Comment: I am expecting (this) refers to ion-checkbox tag.